# How to use will_paginate on a nested resource?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, will-paginate

In my `routes.rb`, I have this nested resource:

```
resources :foos do
  resources :bars, except: :show
end
```

In my `foos/show.html.erb`, I have `<%= render @foo.bars %>` that renders the `bars/_bar.html.erb` partial file to list all the `bars` that belongs to `foo`.

And in my `foos_controller.rb`:

```
def show
  @foo = Foo.find(params[:id])
  @bars = @foo.bars.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 25)
end
```

Then in `foos/show.html.erb`, I have `<%= will_paginate @bars %>`.

And here's where the problem lies. So let's say I have 50 bars, the expected result should be 2 pages with 25 bars for each page right? But mine shows all the 50 bars in each pages.

EDIT: I solved it. The solution is to change `<%= render @foo.bars %>` to `<%= render @bars %>` because I already have the `@bars` variable in `foos_controller.rb`.

Comment: put your will_paginate code in partial page and check

Comment: already tried that but it will result to the paginate being shown in each list.